# How to Use Powershell to find files that do not include a specific user in the ACL

Tags: powershell

I'm a Powershell newbie - I've been trying to put together a script that will recurse through a folder structure and return the path/name of any file that does not contain a specific user account in the ACL.  The closest I've gotten is with this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'Z:\Inbox' -Recurse | Where-Object {(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference.Value -notcontains 'domain\username'} }
```

Although the value that I put in for domain\username exists in the ACLs for the files in the Inbox folder, it still returns those files in the results.  Any ideas greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Just use one `where` statement --> `where {(get-acl $_.fullname).Access.IdentityReference.Value -notcontains 'domain\user'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your commands to the following:

```
Get-ChildItem 'Z:\Inbox' -Recurse |
    Where {(Get-Acl $_.fullname).Access.IdentityReference.Value -notcontains 'domain\user'}
```

In your attempt, the problem is the chaining of `where` commands. The `Get-ChildItem` command returns objects when the `Access` contains an entry that does not include `domain\user` as a `.IdentityReference.Value`. It will almost always have an `Access` entry that doesn't contain that value since almost every folder contains multiple `Access` objects.

What you should be after is only returning objects where the `Access.IdentityReference.Value` collection never contains `domain\user`.